# How to select the effect for the toggle function

Tags: jquery-ui, script#

In Javascript, I can do the following to select the effect of the toggle function:

```
$("#myDiv").toggle("blind", null, "fast");
```

How can I do the same thing in Script#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script# has a mapping for jQuery APIs and jQueryUI - see https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/master/src/Libraries/jQuery/jQuery.Core and https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/master/src/Libraries/jQuery/jQuery.UI.

Likely this class already has what you need defined:
https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/master/src/Libraries/jQuery/jQuery.UI/Effects/Effect/EffectObject.cs

If the particular signature is missing, you should considering making a change to be able to do so yourself, as well as contributing it back so what is there improves for everyone else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to add the new signature